# How do I set a selected option for select in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an object

```
    $scope.colleges = [{"CollegeCode":"40","CollegeName":"College1"},
{"CollegeCode":"35","CollegeName":"College2"},
{"CollegeCode":"32","CollegeName":"College3"},
{"CollegeCode":"15","CollegeName":"College4"}]
```

I'm populating a select element with it's contents

```
<select ng-model="collegeSelection" ng-options="c as c.CollegeName for c in colleges" name="selectCollege"></select>
```

It renders on the page like so

```
<select class="ng-pristine ng-valid" name="selectCollege" ng-options="c as c.CollegeName for c in colleges" ng-model="collegeSelection" style="" selected="selected">
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="0">College1</option>
<option value="1">College2</option>
<option value="2">College3</option>
<option value="3">College4</option>
etc....
```

I'm also binding this select to collegeSelection and when an item is selected the object look like this

```
$scope.collegeSelection = {"CollegeCode":"32","CollegeName":"College"}
```

When someone clicks edit on the page, the college I want selected by default comes from the userToUpdate object.

```
$scope.userToUpdate = {
            Id: 1,
            FirstName: 'John',
            LastName: 'Doe',
            CollegeCode: '35,
            CollegeName: 'College2',
            Active: true
        };
```

When an edit button and the userToUpdate object is populated, I would like the college in the select element to be set to the college in the user object. How could one make this happen? FYI, the value in the rendered select does not match the CollegeCode. It seems angular uses the index from the colleges object. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
<select ng-model="collegeSelection" ng-options="c.CollegeCode as c.CollegeName for c in colleges" name="selectCollege"></select>
    <span>{{collegeSelection}}</span>
    <input type="button" ng-click="switch()" name="switch" value="switch" />
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

        app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $filter) {
            $scope.colleges = [{ "CollegeCode": "40", "CollegeName": "College1" },
                                { "CollegeCode": "35", "CollegeName": "College2" },
                                { "CollegeCode": "32", "CollegeName": "College3" },
                                { "CollegeCode": "15", "CollegeName": "College4" }
            ]

            $scope.switch = function () {
                $scope.collegeSelection = "32";
            };
        });
```

Comment: This method updates the collegeSelection object, but for some reason it doesn't update the actual select element ("doesn't show College2 in the select when collegecode 35 is selected.

Comment: pls check it is working plnkr.co/edit/bejp3iAG7Z15gFjd5lDF?p=preview